# How to filter category collection?

Tags: magento2, category

I am trying to fetch all categories with filter, but it throws following error :

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor::addFieldToFilter

And i have also tried with **`addFieldToFilter`** and **`addAttributeToFilter`** but still it says **invalid method**.
I want all categories filter with Display mode.
Please Help!

Comment: What filter you are applying?

Comment: 'display_mode' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution for the category filter:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection');
$category->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',['eq'=>3]);
```

Comment: Please Avoid using the objectManager concept in the answers, Magento 2 strictly not encourage to use objectManager, of course, we can see some objectManager in core modules, but using objectManager directly is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

the class  `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` is not a collection change your class to:

```
Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory` the solution as follows.


public function __construct(
        Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectioFactory
        ){ $this->collectionFactory = $collectioFactory;}

public function yourFunction()
        {
            $this->collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
            $this->collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',['eq'=>3])
        }
```